# sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (psycopg2.OperationalError) connection to server at127.0.0.1, port 5432 failed:FATAL:password authentication failed

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am trying to create a database for my line bot
but there are some problem connect to database

here is my question

```
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (psycopg2.OperationalError) connection to server at "127.0.0.1", port 5432 failed: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "admin"
```

and I triple check my owner name and password
they are same!!

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'postgresql://admin:er******10@127.0.0.1:5432/userid'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    sql = """
    CREATE TABLE formuser (
    id serial NOT NULL,
    uid character varying(50) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id));

    CREATE TABLE hoteluser (
    id serial NOT NULL,
    uid character varying(50) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id));

    CREATE TABLE booking (
    id serial NOT NULL,
    bid character varying(50) NOT NULL,
    roomtype character varying(20) NOT NULL,
    roomamount character varying(5) NOT NULL,
    datein character varying(20) NOT NULL,
    dateout character varying(20) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id));
    """
    db.engine.execute(sql)
    return "succ"

if __name__ == '__main__':
   app.run(debug=True)
```

I still cant connect my database

Comment: is userid your database name ?

Comment: yes userid is my db name

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that your username is admin ? Just read the error lmao. Or try it out with `postgresql://admin:er******10@localhost:5432/userid`
If this doesn't work, try to change your localhost in the folder `local.ini` Change it to 0.0.0.0

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/w4g1u.png   hundred percent

Comment: Did you try to change the localhost to 0.0.0.0

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).